# how to remove one image in string via php dom

Tags: php, dom

I have an string with some `<img>` in it.

```
$string = '  <img src="pic.jpg">  and <img src="pic2.jpg">';
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img) 
        {
            if($img->getAttribute('src') == 'pic.jpg')
            {
                // I want delete that picture form string
                $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
            }
                else
                  $img->setAttribute('class', 'image normall');

        }
        $string = $doc->saveHTML();
        echo $string;
```

In the end of function when I print `$string`, the target pic has been delete but for other pic,   no add any class to them!

but If I remove `$img->parentNode->removeChild($img);` , the class will add!
what's my wrong?

**EDIT**
please check for this sample string:

```
$string = '  <img src="pic.jpg">  and <img src="pic2.jpg">';
```

Comment: I edit my code..please just run this code in a php online in web....I can not underestand your mean? which part? I do not want remove anything else...fo other class I want add just a class...

Comment: I want add class to all pic. the code works. But if runs this condition `if($img->getAttribute('src') == 'pic.jpg')`  .... the code remove that pic...But unable to add class for other pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete nodes if you iterate **backwards**.

Simply change

```
// Forward iteration
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
```

to

```
// Reverse iteration
for($i = $imgs->length; --$i >= 0;) {
     $img = $imgs->item($i);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#83390

Comment: you are right @Drakes and beated me with 10 second on this. voted-up +10. good

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I solved this with this change....hope help others...

```
$string = '  <img src="pic.jpg">  and <img src="pic2.jpg">';
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $imgs1 = $imgs2 = array();
        foreach($imgs as $img) {
            if($img->getAttribute('src') == 'pic.jpg')
            {
                $imgs1[] = $img;
            }
            else
            $imgs2[] = $img;
        }
        foreach($imgs1 as $img) {
            $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
        }
        foreach ($imgs2 as $img) 
        {

            $img->setAttribute('class', 'image normall');

        }
        $string = $doc->saveHTML();
        echo $string;
```